# D3 cartography: lon/lat circles in wrong place on map (projection)

Tags: d3.js, map-projections, cartography

I have a question about D3 cartography.
I am working on a little project and I am new to D3.

I have started out from this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5914438
Instead of the showing the state-mesh, I would like to show circles on the map in certain locations (lon/lat). I am currently facing a problem that the circles are not on the correct spots on the map. I suspect the problem lies in the special projection that Mike uses. He uses a 1x1 square projection. Probably this is necessary for displaying the tiles. When I project the coordinates, the values are all between -1 and 1. I thought I could fix it by multiplying it width the height and width but it didn't work. Below is my code (snippet does not run because it is missing a file). Thanks for the assistance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

body {
  margin: 0;
}

path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: red;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

circle {
  fill: #fff;
  fill-opacity: 0.4;
  stroke: #111;
}

</style>
<svg>
</svg>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3-tile.v0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
<script>
var pi = Math.PI,
    tau = 2 * pi;

var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

// Initialize the projection to fit the world in a 1×1 square centered at the origin.
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(1 / tau)
    .translate([0, 0]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var tile = d3.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 << 9, 1 << 23])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var raster = svg.append("g");

var vector = svg.append("path");

var circle = svg.append("g")
      
d3.json("/data/flyingsites/AD.json", function(error, flyingsites) {
  if (error) console.log(error); 
  
  // Compute the projected initial center.
  var center = projection([6.2, 45.8]);//45,809718, 6,252314

  // Apply a zoom transform equivalent to projection.{scale,translate,center}.
  svg
      .call(zoom)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
          .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
          .scale(1 << 12)
          .translate(-center[0], -center[1]));

//add flying sites
  circle.selectAll("circle")
   .data(flyingsites.features)
  .enter().append("circle")
   .attr('r',5)
    .attr('cx',function(d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[0]*width})
    .attr('cy',function(d) { return projection(d.geometry.coordinates)[1]*height})
    .style('fill','red')
    
//console.log(flyingsites.features);
//console.log(circle);
});


function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;

  var tiles = tile
      .scale(transform.k)
      .translate([transform.x, transform.y])
      ();

  vector
      .attr("transform", transform)
      .style("stroke-width", 1 / transform.k);
     
  circle
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + transform.x + "," + transform.y + ")");
      
  var image = raster
      .attr("transform", stringify(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
    .selectAll("image")
    .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

  image.exit().remove();

  image.enter().append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0] * 256; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1] * 256; })
      .attr("width", 256)
      .attr("height", 256);
}

function stringify(scale, translate) {
  var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "translate(" + r(translate[0] * scale) + "," + r(translate[1] * scale) + ") scale(" + k + ")";
}

</script>
```

Comment: remove console.log. I am not able to see output.

Comment: ok, but you still will not be able to see the circles since they are in a file which is not included in the snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach you are taking won't work, for one, it doesn't consider the scale (just translate). This is critical as d3-tile uses geometric zooming - it applies a zoom transform (scale and translate) to all the vector elements (not the tiles), this is why the projection projects everything to a one pixel square area and never changes with the zoom.

To solve this, place your circles the same as the example places (and sizes) the polygons:

```
vector
  .attr("d", path(topojson.mesh(us, us.objects.counties)));

circle
  .attr("cx", projection(coord)[0])
  .attr("cy", projection(coord)[1])
  .attr("r", 5/(1<<12));
```

Both of these position features the same way: with the projection only, projecting to a one pixel square. The zoom applies the transform to cover the whole svg. *Also, since we are scaling that one pixel to fit the svg, we want the radius to be scaled appropriately too*.

Now we can apply a transform to the circles the same as the polygons:

```
circle
  .attr("transform", transform);
```

Of course, we could scale the radius down each zoom too, using the zoom k to modify the size of the circle:

```js
var pi = Math.PI,
    tau = 2 * pi;

var width = Math.max(960, window.innerWidth),
    height = Math.max(500, window.innerHeight);

// Initialize the projection to fit the world in a 1×1 square centered at the origin.
var projection = d3.geoMercator()
    .scale(1 / tau)
    .translate([0, 0]);

var path = d3.geoPath()
    .projection(projection);

var tile = d3.tile()
    .size([width, height]);

var zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([1 << 11, 1 << 14])
    .on("zoom", zoomed);

var svg = d3.select("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

var raster = svg.append("g");

var vector = svg.append("circle");

  // Compute the projected initial center.
  var center = projection([-98.5, 39.5]);

  // Apply a zoom transform equivalent to projection.{scale,translate,center}.
  svg
      .call(zoom)
      .call(zoom.transform, d3.zoomIdentity
          .translate(width / 2, height / 2)
          .scale(1 << 12)
          .translate(-center[0], -center[1]));

  var coord = [-100,40]
    
  vector
      .attr("cx", projection(coord)[0])
   .attr("cy", projection(coord)[1])
   .attr("r", 5/(1<<12));

function zoomed() {
  var transform = d3.event.transform;

  var tiles = tile
      .scale(transform.k)
      .translate([transform.x, transform.y])
      ();

  vector
      .attr("transform", transform)
      .attr("r", 5/transform.k);

  var image = raster
      .attr("transform", stringify(tiles.scale, tiles.translate))
    .selectAll("image")
    .data(tiles, function(d) { return d; });

  image.exit().remove();

  image.enter().append("image")
      .attr("xlink:href", function(d) { return "http://" + "abc"[d[1] % 3] + ".tile.openstreetmap.org/" + d[2] + "/" + d[0] + "/" + d[1] + ".png"; })
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d[0] * 256; })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d[1] * 256; })
      .attr("width", 256)
      .attr("height", 256);
}

function stringify(scale, translate) {
  var k = scale / 256, r = scale % 1 ? Number : Math.round;
  return "translate(" + r(translate[0] * scale) + "," + r(translate[1] * scale) + ") scale(" + k + ")";
}
```

```html
<svg></svg>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-tile.v0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
```

Ultimately d3-tile can be a bit confusing to start with because you are using quite a few coordinate systems (tile, zoom, pixel, projected, geographic), and normally aren't projecting the entire map to a 1 pixel square.

Comment: I see what you mean. I specifically used the translate because I always want the circle to be radius 5 independent of the zoom-level (as a placemark). Do I need to do a full transformation and then a resize?

Comment: I updated the answer to show scaling the circle (keeping it with a radius of 5 pixels no matter the zoom).

Comment: Thank you very much. It works like a charm.
I wonder if this method will give me performance issues when 5000 circles all need to be resized after zoom.

Comment: It could - you could filter the circles possibly based on what's visible if you notice speed issues (but this is not a simple as it could be with d3-tile), canvas circles could be an improvement too (around ~5000 elements a difference should start to be seen, but this requires a fair bit of modification), circle clustering could also be suitable, but there aren't many example of this (I've been slowly refining a module for this using quad trees, [eg](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/34d41d92aa3c2ff61cce4ae0bd23106a) (example doesn't use d3-tile though)).

Comment: I still have a problem when I change "vector" to a group and add the circles to the group. In the zoom function, I use:

vector
      .attr("transform", transform)
      .selectAll("circle")
      .attr("r", 5/transform.k);

It shows me all the circles in the right place, but I also get one big border of a circle around the whole map. I want to show a picture, but I don't know where it is appropriate.